# Deletion of override.conf

Tags: 18.04, systemd, ubuntu-mate

I put this in /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf.

It speeds up the bootup time of my computer.

```
[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
AccuracySec=1h
RandomizedDelaySec=30min
```

However, something seems to be deleting this file as shown when I run

```
systemd-analyze
```

Bootup time went from 42 seconds to 1.5 minutes.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Just to clarify: is the file actually deleted? Or are you concluding that based on the the `systemd-analyze` output? And how did you create that file?

Comment: I do not know if file was actually deleted. I used sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer to create override.conf. @DK Bose